# How to make a OpenGl (GLUT) rotate-Animation?

Tags: opengl, rotation, glut

I have made a playing field and it would rotate 180 degrees.
Unfortunately you can not see how it turns more and more slowly.
I only see the final "twist".

```
/**
@brief Rotates the Gamefield 180° with an turn animaion
*/
void flipGamefield180degree (){
        for (int i = 0; i < 180; i++){
            glRotatef(1, 0, 1, 0);
            glutPostRedisplay();
            Sleep(20);
        }
}


void display(void)
{

    // Löscht den Bildschirm
   glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   // Zeichenfarbe setzen  
   glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
   glLoadIdentity ();             

   // _,_,_ wo steht die Kamera, _,_,_ wo hin, wo ist oben?
   gluLookAt (0.0, 0.0, 10, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);


   // Rotation X-Achse
   rotating(0);
   // Rotation Y-Achse
   rotating(1);
   // Rotation Z-Achse
   rotating(2);

   if (flip180degree){
       flipGamefield180degree();
   }

   /*glRotatef(15,0,1,0);
   glRotatef(-15,1,0,0);
   */

   glTranslatef(-5.5, -6 ,0);
   glPushMatrix();
   drawGameField(false, 10);
   glPopMatrix();

   glPushMatrix();
   glTranslatef(11, 0 ,0);
   glPushMatrix();
   drawGameField(true, 10);
   glPopMatrix();
   glPopMatrix();

   //drawShipOnField(s1, feldSpieler);
   drawShipOnField(s1, feldSpieler);

   //glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
   /*glColor3f(0, 0, 1); 
   glutSolidCube(1);
   glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);*/
  /* glTranslatef(5, 0, 0);
   drawGameField(true, 10);*/
   //glutSolidTeapot(1.0);


   //glRotatef(30,1.0,0.0,0.0);






   glFlush ();
}
```

Comment: a similar question and it worked for me [stackoverflow.com/questions/20396485/how-to-animate-a-rotation-triggered-by-a-key-in-opengl-and-glut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396485/how-to-animate-a-rotation-triggered-by-a-key-in-opengl-and-glut#)

Answer (score 1):

`glRotatef(1, 0, 1, 0);` I assume that's a typo and should have an `i` somewhere?

Your call to glRotate() is beign reset by part of your display code - openGL is a state machine, everytime you change anything it 'sticks' until something else changes.

It would be better to have an angle variable that you update in the draw routine

Comment: yeah that works. thanks :) how can  i give you a star or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> void flipGamefield180degree (){
>     for (int i = 0; i < 180; i++){
>         glRotatef(1, 0, 1, 0);
>         glutPostRedisplay();
>         Sleep(20);
>     }
> }
> ```

Problem 1: glutPostRedisplay() only queues a display event, it doesn't actually perform the drawing. Solution: Use a idle function that constantly calls glutPostRedisplay (if a animation is running) and use the system time to do the animation.

Problem 2: OpenGL is a statefull drawing API, not a scene graph. That one glRotate in your loop doesn't make it into the drawing state, since you start off with a glLoadIdentity (good). So instead set a variable, and put that rotation into the drawing path.

Comment: Now i have another problem. I can only use the turn animation 1x. 

    void flipGamefield180degree (){
      
     if (flipangle < 180){
      cout << "1\n";
       flipangle += 1;
       glRotatef(flipangle, 0, 1, 0);
       glutPostRedisplay();
       Sleep(10);
    
     }
    
     else {
      glRotatef(180, 0, 1, 0);
      
     }
       
    
    }

....

    void display(void){
     if (flip180degree){
        flipGamefield180degree();
       }
    }