# How to animate a rotation triggered by a key in OpenGL and GLUT?

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I want to rotate a simple cube in OpenGL using GLUT in C. The rotation will occur when I press a key.

If I use `glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)` the cube will rotate instantly without an animation. I would like to rotate it slowly so it takes about 2 seconds to complete the rotation.

Comment: Use Math to calculate the animation.

Comment: glRotatef(0.00001f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) ? or anyway, use a smaller delta(angle)

Comment: You can use the button press to start a glutTimerFunc, which is a function that is called every x ms see https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node64.html#SECTION000819000000000000000 and using that function you can update the rotation more gradually

Comment: I think like so many newbies you confuse OpenGL with a scene graph. OpenGL does not maintain a scene, there are no models in OpenGL. There is just a pixel based framebuffer canvas (offered by the operating system) and OpenGL will just **draw** to it points, lines or triangles. Once it's done drawing things it has no recollection about it whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Create a keyboard callback that toggles a bool and a timer callback that updates an angle:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

char spin = 0;
void keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    if( key == ' ' )
    {
        spin = !spin;
    }
}

float angle = 0;
void timer( int value )
{
    if( spin )
    {
        angle += 3;
    }

    glutTimerFunc( 16, timer, 0 );
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective( 45, w / h, 0.1, 10 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt( 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 );

    glColor3ub( 255, 0, 0 );
    glRotatef( angle, 0, 0, 1 );
    glutWireCube( 1 );

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 640, 480 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );
    glutTimerFunc( 0, timer, 0 );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```